# Nginx and PHP-cgi - can't file_get_contents of any website on the server

Tags: php, curl, nginx, file-get-contents

This one is best explained by code I think. From the web directory:

```
vi get.php
```

Add this php to get.php

```
<?
echo file_get_contents("http://IPOFTHESERVER/");
?>
```

IPOFTHESERVER is the IP of the server that nginx and PHP are running on.

```
php get.php
```

Returns the contents of the (default) website hosted at that I.P. BUT

http://IPOFTHESERVER/get.php

..returns a **504 Gateway Time-out**. It's the same with curl. It's the same using the PHP exec command and GET. However, from the command line directly it all works fine.

I've replicated it on 2 nginx servers. For some reason nginx won't allow me to make an HTTP connection to the server its running on, via PHP (unless it's via the command line).

Anyone got any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the php.ini and make sure that the `allow_url_fopen` setting is enabled?

Comment: did you try with the loopback address "127.0.0.1" ? if that works I think there is a missing entry in /etc/hosts

Comment: @Brad - allow_url_fopen is ON.

Comment: @jknair - Just tried it. Exactly the same story. Not sure it has anything to do with /etc/hosts. GET http://127.0.0.1 works fine. It's only when run via PHP there's a problem.

Comment: @Rastaboy, By IPOFTHESERVER, you mean the external IP correct? The main thing I can think of is the nginx configuration may not be set to listen on the IP, but rather a domain. Can you pastebin or post your nginx configuration file for the vhost (or the nginx.conf if no vhost)? That might help us figure it out.

Comment: @Brad. Thanks for your comment. It got me thinking on the right track. I needed to change PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN to 2 in the /etc/init.d/php-cgi file. Basically, with only 1 child the same worker couldn't send/receive data at the same time. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that your not running into worker depletion on the PHP side of things, this was the issue on my lab server setup which was configured to save RAM.

Basically I forgot that your using a single worker to process the main page been displayed to the end-user, then the get_file_contents() function is basically generating a separate HTTP request to the same web server, effectively requiring 2 workers for a single page load.

As the first page was using the last worker there was none avaliable for the get_file_contents function, therefore Nginx eventually replied with a 504 on the first page because there was no reply on the reverse proxy request.

Comment: Thanks iTom, that's exactly what was happening. I needed to change PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN to 2 in the /etc/init.d/php-cgi file and all is now good.

Comment: I changed the ``pm.max_children = 1`` config, which is equivalent to PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN in the PHP-FPM site-config file.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what was happening to me! On my fedora machine I had to change my pm.max_children = 1 to something higher to solve this!

Answer (score -1):

Check if allow_url_fopen is set to true in your php.ini.

Comment: Yes, allow_url_fopen is set to ON. It works fine with other URLS. Just none that are hosted on the *same* server.