# file_get_contents 504 gateway timeout after merging project to amazon EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

Checking out the project and the functionalities , I did recognize that `file_get_contents` for internal files doesn't work at all. It always give me the same error :

> file_get_contents 504 gateway timeout

How can it be fixed?

Comment: You need to provide more background to your issue. I suspect it's a security group issue on AWS. From where are you calling `file_get_contents`, from a non-aws machine TO your new ec2?

Comment: no , from the new ec2 machine ...for outside files it work fine.

Comment: Okay so to confirm you have the issue when you use file_get_contents on a local file? And how are you running the script? From web browser or command line?

Comment: yeah local file and from web browser.

Comment: Thanks. Last question, is it an extremely large file you are trying to load? It could be that you are hitting the php_max_execution limit, and so the request eventually times out. Add this to the top of your script `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` Also, try running the script from the CLI to ensure it works that way.

Comment: no it's not a large script.sorry for the question : how to try to execute it from the CLI ?

Comment: Assuming you can ssh into the machine, simply change directories to where the script is, and run `php name_of_script.php`. If there are errors, it will display them on the CLI.

Comment: i don't have acces with ssh,what i can use is aws s3 commands...

Comment: Are you referencing the file name as a url? If so, just reference the file from its absolute path. Unless you mean you are trying to access a file on S3? Can you post your script?

Comment: Are you using nginx or Apache? If nginx, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230719/nginx-and-php-cgi-cant-file-get-contents-of-any-website-on-the-server

Comment: no we're using apache.

Comment: Hm interesting, still see that answer, in the comments, it mentions changes to the PHP configuration. I would try that.

Comment: still doesn't fix the problem , plz any help !!!

Comment: Can you look at the apache logs atleast? Might be located in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: it's been fixed , it was a problem about ip restrictions.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**For Nginx server**

Check that you are not running into worker depletion on the PHP side of things, I had face this issue too on my lab server setup which was configured to save RAM.
Basically I forgot that you are using a single worker to process the main page been displayed to the end-user, then the get_file_contents() function is basically generating a separate HTTP request to the same web server, effectively requiring 2 workers for a single page load.
As the first page was using the last worker there was none available for the get_file_contents function, therefore Nginx eventually replied with a 504 on the first page because there was no reply on the reverse proxy request.